# Соединить таблицы

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, join

Нужно слить таблицы  вида 'df1', 'df2', 'df3' в таблицу вида "result"[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Читайте справку по функции ВПР().

Comment: @Akina, я понял, что нужно в *python*... Да и в Excel сама *ВПР* с таким не справится (в таблицах 2 и 3 не все значения), нужна помощь

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, исходные данные в тестовом виде, а не в виде скриншотов, если надеетесь получить ответ.

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @vikttur А я так понял, что это надо как раз в Excel, но рулить процессом из питона. Не, можно, конечно, дурью маяться и итерать по одной клетке - но нафига?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

Исходные DF:

```
In [77]: d1
Out[77]:
    A   B
1  A1  B1
2  A2  B2
3  A3  B3
4  A4  B4
5  A5  B5
6  A6  B6
7  A7  B7
8  A8  B8

In [78]: d2
Out[78]:
    D
1  D1
4  D4
8  D8

In [79]: d3
Out[79]:
    F
1  F1
5  F5
7  F7
```

Решение - воспользуйтесь [pd.concat(...)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
In [80]: res = pd.concat([d1, d2, d3], axis="columns").ffill()
```

Результат:

```
In [81]: res
Out[81]:
    A   B   D   F
1  A1  B1  D1  F1
2  A2  B2  D1  F1
3  A3  B3  D1  F1
4  A4  B4  D4  F1
5  A5  B5  D4  F5
6  A6  B6  D4  F5
7  A7  B7  D4  F7
8  A8  B8  D8  F7
```